# add bash script to crontab via bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I would like to add date with filename to my bash script which would be added to crontab file via script. The problem is entry in crontab file is already having the date appended. But my requirement is to have the date command in crontab.

```
crontab -l > "$FILENAME"
if grep -i cron "$FILENAME"; then
    echo "Cron Job already present in User's crontab file"
else
    echo "*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_`date +\%Y\%m\%dT\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1 " >> mycron
    crontab mycron
    echo "Crontab added to User's Crontab"
fi
```

Actual :

```
*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_20211217053830.log 2>&1
```

Requirement :

```
*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.log 2>&1
```

I have also tried to add escape characters but didn't seem to work

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  Just have `/home/cronjob/cron.sh` compute the date and do `exec > /home/cronjob/myjob_$(date ...) 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your crontab entry is close. Since *%*'s are special (newline) characters in a crontab file, escaping them should give the desired result:

```
*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1
```

The echo-line that accomplishes this is:

```
echo "*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_\`date +\\%Y\\%m\\%dT\\%H\\%M\\%S\`.log 2>&1 " >> mycron
```

I verified that this works in Ubuntu.

Additionally, adding the line `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the crontab file (above the entries) ensures that *bash* interprets the crontab entries. While you likely will not need it it this case, it would enable more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use cat

```
cat << '==CRONTAB_LINE==' >> mycron
*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S).log 2>&1 
==CRONTAB_LINE==
```

Result

```
crontab -e
*/5 * * * * bash -x /home/cronjob/cron.sh > /home/cronjob/myjob_$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S).log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert the command output you have to replace

```
`date +\%Y\%m\%dT\%H\%M\%S`
```

with `$(date +\%Y\%m\%dT\%H\%M\%S)`